# How dataframe, how to calculate row means of conditional values

Tags: r, dataframe

For the example (even if my problem applies to a much bigger table), let's say I have a dataframe of this type:

```
> df = data.frame(rep(NA,3),rep(NA,3),c(-6,5,NA),c(-2,-1,4),c(NA,2,-3),c(1,-3,2))
> colnames(df) = c("Positive mean","Negative mean","a","b","c","d")

> df
  Positive mean Negative mean  a  b  c  d
1            NA            NA -6 -2 NA  1
2            NA            NA  5 -1  2 -3
3            NA            NA NA  4 -3  2
```

I would like to be able to compute for each row, the mean of the positive values and the mean of the negative ones. In order the obtain the final table:

```
> df
  Positive mean Negative mean  a  b  c  d
1           1.0            -4 -6 -2 NA  1
2           3.5            -2  5 -1  2 -3
3           3.0            -3 NA  4 -3  2
```

So, I would like to know if there is a way to do it without using loops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `apply` on `MARGIN = 1` (rows), select the relevant values (subset positive or negative values), and take `mean`. Use `na.rm = TRUE` to get rid of `NA` values when taking `mean`

```
apply(df[,-(1:2)], MARGIN = 1, function(x) mean(x[x>0], na.rm = TRUE))
#[1] 1.0 3.5 3.0
apply(df[,-(1:2)], 1, function(x) mean(x[x<0], na.rm = TRUE))
#[1] -4 -2 -3
```

Comment: Why would a sort be needed?

Comment: More efficient (and less obscure) to use na.rm=TRUE

Answer (score 1):

This is a "vectorized" approach:

```
df[[1]] <- rowMeans( df[3:6]*(df[3:6] >0) , na.rm=TRUE)
df[[2]] <- rowMeans( df[3:6]*(df[3:6] < 0) , na.rm=TRUE)

>  df
  Positive_mean Negative_mean  a  b  c  d
1     0.3333333     -2.666667 -6 -2 NA  1
2     1.7500000     -1.000000  5 -1  2 -3
3     2.0000000     -1.000000 NA  4 -3  2
```

On a note of style, most regular users of R would not leave a space in a column name, but would instead use one of camelCase, ".", or "_".